# Fastest way to convert char[] to trimmed String

Tags: java, string, trim

In my program I need to convert `char[]` of fixed size into **trimmed String** (without blank spaces taken from an array). At the moment I do `new String(array).trim()` but I would like to avoid `trim()` if possible. Any advice how to do it better?
Best Regards.

Comment: give a sample char[] with elements in it

Comment: So you want to get rid of the spaces at the start and end? Trim does so. What you say with "spaces taken from an array" is not achievable using trim.

Comment: The example char is [1,2,3, , , , , ,], the resulting String should be 123 (no spaces left).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but I would like to avoid trim() if possible. Any advice how to do it better?

Do not look for any alternative and `trim()` is smart enough which uses `substring()` method internally. That is fast enough.

Any looping or reg-ex based solutions will hit you hard.

Answer (score 3):

If you use **trim** source code and rewrite it a little bit, you can remove unused (in your case) **substring** method:

trim source code:

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

Test:

```
public static char[] value = new char[]{' ', ' ', 't', 'w', 's', ' ', ' ', ' '};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    normal();
    optimized();
}

public static void normal() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    String s = new String(value).trim();

    System.out.println("normal   : '" + s + "' " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + "ns");
}

public static void optimized() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    String s = new String(value, st, len - st);


    System.out.println("optimized: '" + s + "' " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + "ns");
}
```

The output:

```
run:
normal   : 'tws' 41656ns
optimized: 'tws' 7546ns
```

So, **your version of new trimmed string** will save you some time.

Comment: These times mean absolutely nothing. You should use jmh if you want to microbenchmark the two possibilities.

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev 1# - I provided source code of trim function from JDK.
2# But it is obvious that we removed unused susbtring call.